# Extraer y comparar DNS en C

Tags: c, dns, filtro, ping

Partiendo de mi función velocidad_media, usada para extraer la velocidad de respuesta media a la llamada tipo ping a una IP, quiero usarla para obtener lo mismo de un servidor DNS que me viene dado bajo la variable str. Por algún motivo, no me funciona. A continuación la función de la que hablo, que funciona correctamente con las IP's que lee:

```
int velocidad_media(const char* ip)
{
    const char* const Delim = "Media = ";
    printf("\n    Extrayendo velocidad media de %s", ip);

    char cmd[64];
    sprintf(cmd, "ping %s", ip);
    FILE* p = _popen(cmd, "r");
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), p))
    {
        char* s = NULL;
        if ((s = strstr(line, Delim)) != NULL)
        {
            _pclose(p);
            return atoi(s + strlen(Delim));
        }
    }
    _pclose(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Y mi módulo de donde saco "str" como cadena de caracteres:

```
int main(void)
{

    char* c;
    char* end;
    char line[100], str[100], dns1[100];

    FILE* dns = fopen("dns.txt", "r");
    if (!dns) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, dns)) {
        if (!strstr(line, "DNS")) {
            continue;
        }

        c = strchr(line, ':');
        c += 2;
        end = c;
        while (*end != '\0') {
            end++;
            if (!isdigit(*end) && *end != '.') {
                break;
            }
        }

        *end = '\0';
        strcpy(str, c);

        int dns1 = velocidad_media(str);

    }
        printf("\n\n    Velocidad de respuesta media: %d ms.\n", dns1);
        printf("    DNS seleccionada: %s", str);
    }
```

Lo que necesito es ser capaz de extraer el tiempo de respuesta medio del servidor DNS en cuestión. Ejecutando este código me ofrece un número ficticio de unos 5 ó 6 dígitos cuando, ejecutando la función ping manualmente por cmd, ésta es fiable y del tipo "3 ms" aprox. Sin embargo, str en el segundo printf me printa correctamente ese servidor DNS...

A continuación el formato de mi llamada al sistema (dns.txt):

```
Configuración para la interfaz "Ethernet"
    Servidores DNS configurados a través de DHCP:  80.58.61.250
                                          80.58.61.254
    Registrar con el sufijo:           Solo el principal
```

Comment: Pregunta modificada con más información.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el contenido del archivo dns.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Noto que tu código está incompleto, pero suponiendo que tu archivo dns.txt contenga lo siguiente:

```
DNS: 8.8.8.8
DNS: 8.8.4.4
```

El código para recorrer las lineas bajo windows, obtener la dirección IP, ejecutar 'ping' de dicha dirección, obtener la media de cada linea y finalizar mostrando cual es la IP que corresponde a la menor, sería algo así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

// C no tiene manejo de booleanos 'per se', asi que esto sirve mas claridad 
// a las comparaciones booleanas.
#define true 1
#define false 0

double velocidad_media(const char* ip)
{
    const char* const Delim = "Media = ";
    printf("    Extrayendo velocidad media de %s: ", ip);

    char cmd[64];
    sprintf(cmd, "ping %s", ip);
    FILE* p = _popen(cmd, "r");
    char line[256];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), p))
    {
        char* s = NULL;
        if ((s = strstr(line, Delim)) != NULL)
        {
            _pclose(p);
            return atof(s + strlen(Delim));
        }
    }
    _pclose(p);

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char* c;
    char* end;
    char line[100], str[100], str_dns_ok[100];
    double velocidad, velocidad_minima = 1000000.0;


    FILE* file = fopen("dns.txt", "r");
    if (!file) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("Testeando velocidades de DNS...\n");
    int dns_seleccionada = false;
    while ( fgets(line, 100, file) != NULL ) {

        velocidad = 0;

        if (!strstr(line, "DNS")) {
            continue;
        }

        c = strchr(line, ':');
        c += 2;
        // Agregué la eliminación del \n final.
        c = strtok(c,"\n");
        end = c;
        // Determinamos si es un valor válido antes de ejecutarlo:
        int es_valido = false;
        if( strlen(end) > 0 ) {
            es_valido = true;
            do {
                if (!isdigit(*end) && *end != '.') {
                    es_valido = false;
                    break;
                }
                end++; 
            }
            while ( strlen(end) > 0 && es_valido );
        }

        // Si es un valor válido:
        if( es_valido == true ) {
            strcpy (str, c);            
            velocidad = velocidad_media(str);
            printf("%f ms.\n", velocidad);
            // Determinamos si la velocidad obtenida es la menor del archivo.
            if( velocidad < velocidad_minima ) {
                dns_seleccionada = true;
                strcpy ( str_dns_ok, str );
                velocidad_minima = velocidad;
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("    * La cadena '%s' no es un DNS válido.\n",c);
        }
    }

    if( dns_seleccionada == true )
        printf("DNS seleccionada: %s (%f ms)\n", str_dns_ok, velocidad_minima);
    else 
        printf("El archivo dns.txt no contiene valores de válidos.");

    return 0;
}
```

La salida será algo así:

```
Testeando velocidades de DNS...
    Extrayendo velocidad media de 8.8.8.8: 217.000000 ms.
    Extrayendo velocidad media de 8.8.4.4: 464.000000 ms.
DNS seleccionada: 8.8.8.8 (217.000000 ms)
```

De ahí puedes adaptarlo a tu necesidad. Es mejorable, pero con esto ya tendrás una buena idea de como implementarlo. Presta atención sobre todo al manejo de cadenas y los controles aplicados. Suerte!

Saludos!

Comment: Muy buenas Leonardo, y gracias por tu ayuda inestimable. Ahora actualizaré con el formato del archivo. De todos modos, estoy atascado en la redirección de mis servidores DNS (no logro guardar el resultado de mi llamada al sistema sin que afecte al resto), así que no sé cómo podría trabajar con ellos a través de la llamada al sistema "netsh interface ipv4 show dnsservers" + variable adaptador. Es decir, ¿sería posible llevar a cabo todo ese proceso sustituyéndolo por esa llamada al sistema con variable añadida en lugar de acceder a un archivo .txt redireccionado? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Si, es posible. Tienes que organizar bien el código, dividiéndolo en procesos claros que te sugiero que lo separes en funciones para dejar un main lo mas sencillo posible: una llamada a función para obtener los dns en un array de char*, otra para recorrer los char* y ejecute la rutina de obtener solo el char* que apunta a la dirección con menor tiempo. A partir de ahí puedes llamar a una nueva función que configure el mejor dns como el por defecto, si es lo que necesitas.

Comment: Tienes todas las herramientas en este código. Te sugiero que hagas pequeñas pruebas, ejecutando los comandos a mano, y luego lo codifiques usando las llamadas popen y recorriendo las salidas para determinar si se ejecutó con éxito. No dudes de usar el printf todo lo necesario para ver que es lo que está conteniendo cada variable. El no suponer es la clave.

Comment: No olvides poner +1 a la respuesta, esto ayuda a seguir colaborando. Saludos!